# SQL Server syntax correction

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to create a SQL Server stored procedure but I am getting some errors.

```
create procedure testproc8
as
begin
    declare @x int 
    declare @z int
    declare @y money OUTPUT

    set @y = (select (sum([OrderQty] * [UnitPrice]) / sum([OrderQty])) * @x
              from [dbo].[Transactions]
              where [ProductID] = @z
              group by [ProductID])

    return 
end
```

Here are the errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure testproc8, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 60]
> Incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure testproc8, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 60]
> Must declare the scalar variable "@y"

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is for MS SQL Server I think; Is this correct? Please always specify the db vendor because "SQL" is too generic

Comment: Are you intending to pass parameters to your procedure when you execute it? Or do you intend to set the values of your local variables via code inside your procedure? Do you want, as output, a resultset of more than 1 row or just 1 single sum?

Comment: yes, i planned to have x and z as parameters...  with a single num as a result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `Output` and just select `@y` for your result

```
create proc testproc8
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here 
as
begin
declare @x int 
--set @x = certain integer 'if your stored procedure did not have parameters'
declare @z int
--set @z = certain integer 'if your stored procedure did not have parameters'
declare @y money 
set @y = 
(
    select (SUM([OrderQty]*[UnitPrice])/SUM([OrderQty])) * @x
    from [dbo].[Transactions]
    where [ProductID] = @z
    group by [ProductID]
)

select @y
end
```

Comment: No need for `@y` at all, you could just `select`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testproc8
@x AS INT,
@z AS INT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @y money

set @y = (
    select (SUM([OrderQty]*[UnitPrice])/SUM([OrderQty])) * @x
    from [dbo].[Transactions]
    where [ProductID] = @z
    group by [ProductID]
)

SELECT @y

END
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. code only answer, will not be easily understood.